# created .webm from .mp4 with ffmpeg is async due to start_time>0 in video stream

Tags: video, asynchronous, ffmpeg, mp4, webm

since a couple of days i'm trying to figure out a solution for syncronization issue, using ffmpeg as a transcoding application.

i create a 1-fps .webm-preview of my .mp4-Video with the following ffmpeg command line:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libvpx -b:v 500k -ss 0 -qmin 10 -qmax 42 -maxrate 500k -bufsize 1000k -vf scale=768:576 -an -r 1 -g 0 -y output.webm
```

after my .webm-format is transcoded, i realize that f.e. position 00:00:10.000 in both videos does not have the same image.

after reading parts of the ffmpeg documentation, i found the parameter -vsync

> -vsync parameter
>
> 0, passthrough: Each frame is passed with its timestamp from the demuxer to the muxer.
>
> 1, cfr: Frames will be duplicated and dropped to achieve exactly the requested constant frame rate.
>
> 2, vfr: Frames are passed through with their timestamp or dropped so as to prevent 2 frames from having the same timestamp.
>
> drop: As passthrough but destroys all timestamps, making the muxer generate fresh timestamps based on frame-rate.
>
> -1, auto: Chooses between 1 and 2 depending on muxer capabilities. This is the default method.

As i'm kind of new to ffmpeg, i'd like to ask for help to spare my troubles.

Anybody?

Update: Digging deeper i found out that my mp4-Source had an offset in the beginning.

So i should solve this problem first.

Documenting my work, i found out, that the video-Stream in my .mp4-Format has the following offset, defined as start_time.

```
ffprobe -v quiet -show_streams -print_format json -i archiv.mp4 
{
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
            "profile": "High",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_time_base": "1/100",
            "codec_tag_string": "avc1",
            [..]
            "start_time": "1.080000",
            [..]
    ]
```

Is there a way, resetting this start_time of the stream by ffmpeg? Right now, im using the following command-line:

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -vf yadif -c:v libx264 -crf 24 -c:a libmp3lame -y -strict -2 -b:v 4000k -copyts -start_at_zero archiv.mp4
```

Comment: did you manage to solve this?